# How to turn off HtmlBeautify for md files vim

Tags: vim

I want to turn off htmlbeautify for md files.

I am using the plug in [vim-jsbeautify](https://github.com/maksimr/vim-jsbeautify) and use a plug in on save the following way: in my `vimfiles/ftplugin` folder

```
├── ftplugin
│   ├── html
│   │   └── main.vim
```

I have added a html folder and added a `main.vim` file with the content

```
 autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call HtmlBeautify()
 noremap <buffer> <c-f> :call HtmlBeautify()<cr>
```

so that html files are formatted on save. The command `verbose set filetype` returns

```
  filetype=markdown
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
```

for md files

Some how the `md` files are also considered of html files. how can I turn this of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim` you will find the following line:

```
runtime! ftplugin/html.vim ftplugin/html_*.vim ftplugin/html/*.vim
```

This will source html ftplugins for markdown files as Markdown uses html in its syntax.

One way to prevent this is do add an `:if` to avoid these inclusion for markdown.

```
if &filetype == 'html'
  autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call HtmlBeautify()
  noremap <buffer> <c-f> :call HtmlBeautify()<cr>
endif
```

Comment: thank you, Peter. Your solution with the explanation was great.